# rviz can't launch,report Bus error (core dumbed) everytime

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have Ubuntu 12.04 along with ROS hydro, and I can't start rviz, every time I start it the following error occur,

Bus error (core dumbed)

I tried rebooting many times and still same error. I have the following graphic card

description: VGA compatible controller

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6530M/6550M] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell Mobility Radeon HD 5650
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at cfee0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at cfe00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
Kernel modules: fglrx, radeon
```

and when I use `rosrun rviz rviz -l`, the last few line show

```
[ INFO] [1384653613.201742639]: GLSL compiled : rviz/glsl150/box.geom(with_lighting)WARNING: 0:52: warning(#332) :gl_TexCoord is only available in compatibility profile
WARNING: 0:55: warning(#332) :gl_FrontColor is only available in compatibility profile
WARNING: 0:55: warning(#332) :gl_FrontColor is only available in compatibility profile
WARNING: 0:55: warning(#332) :gl_FrontColor is only available in compatibility profile

[ INFO] [1384653613.202094589]: Parsing script point_cloud_tile.material
[ INFO] [1384653613.203058844]: Parsing script default_pick_and_depth.material
[ INFO] [1384653613.203942498]: Parsing script indexed_8bit_image.material
[ INFO] [1384653613.204618496]: Parsing script point_cloud_point.material
[ INFO] [1384653613.205564755]: Parsing script point_cloud_square.material
[ INFO] [1384653613.206606778]: Parsing script point_cloud_flat_square.material
[ INFO] [1384653613.207181959]: Parsing script point_cloud_sphere.material
[ INFO] [1384653613.207681982]: Parsing script point_cloud_box.material
[ INFO] [1384653613.208177118]: Compiler error: reference to a non existing object in point_cloud_box.material(47)
[ INFO] [1384653613.208323411]: Parsing script arial.fontdef
[ INFO] [1384653613.208549127]: Finished parsing scripts for resource group rviz
[ INFO] [1384653613.222249534]: GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow "OgreWindow(1)", 100x30 windowed  miscParams: externalGLControl= macAPI=carbon parentWindowHandle=69206050 
[ INFO] [1384653613.258647076]: GLXWindow::create used FBConfigID = 39
Bus error (core dumped)
```

My CPU was  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 480  @ 2.67GHz.

Can someone please help,

3601

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101991/rviz-can%27t-launch,report-bus-error-(core-dumbed)-everytime/) by [3601](https://answers.ros.org/users/8876/3601/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it with reinstall rviz.

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-hydro-rviz
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
```

---

Originally posted by [3601](https://answers.ros.org/users/8876/3601/) with karma: 16 on 2013-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0